# Echo Memcache Key Value?

Tags: php, memcached

I'm having problems finding out how to just echo the value of a specific key in Memcache. I've spent the last few hours looking everywhere and can't find what I need.

Here's what the memcache array looks like (the value of mcservers changes periodically):

```
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:8:"str_attr";s:9:"mc servers";s:8:"int_attr";i:5;}
```

I just want the value of `int_attr` echoed on my php page.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's something wrong with your memcache. Actually,memcache returns deserialize item,but yours seems a serialized string,sometimes,access memcache via a Tokyo Tyrant client,maybe get this error.Pls check it.
Otherwise,you can get the int_attr by those codes immediately:

```
$obj = $memcache->get($key);echo $obj->int_attr;
```